# I want to replace 52/36 chainrings with 50/34 chainrings on a Praxis Works

Tags: chainring

I want to replace 52/36  chainrings with 50/34 chainrings on a Praxis Works. Is this possible without changing the crank? Also if possible would other modification be required such as the chain and possible the  front derailleur

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [road Praxis chainrings page](https://praxiscycles.com/product/road-rings/), 52/36 through 48/32 ring sets are all offered in 110mm BCD. All the roads cranks seem to have an evenly spaced 5 bolt pattern.

Without knowing exactly what crank you have I can't say for sure, but it seems likely you can fit smaller rings.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, If you can buy a separate ring then you better replace just the small ring from 36 to 34 teeth.
Doing this has some benefits;

1) You probably don't need to adjust Front Derailleur. Just double check if front shifting is fine, be careful on derailleur height from big ring and L limiter for small ring. I did this on my 2 bikes, never drop a chain during shifting.

2) You can leave the chain as it is. No need to shorten it. Because Shimano's method measuring the chain length with big ring in front and big cog in the back, small chainring is not involve.

3) Wider gear range. High gear remains the same ratio while low gear gets lower ratio. A jump in ratio might be a little too high for racer, but it is beneficial for non-racer.

Comment: I've been running this combination (52/34) on Ultegra Di2 and mechanical for over two years now on two different bikes. Shimano discourages but it works without any trouble (no thrown chains, smooth shifting).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it with your current cranks as long as you get chainrings with the correct BCD (Bolt Center Distance). How to measure your current BCD: https://www.wolftoothcomponents.com/pages/how-to-measure-bolt-circle-diameter-bcd

You might want to adjust your front derailleur so that it's a few mm more towards the bottom bracket (positioned slightly lower on the seat tube than it was originally), in order to compensate for the slightly smaller diameter of the new chain rings. 
How to check if chain length is correct:

The chain might need to be shortened by 2 links to get perfect chain length but it should work with current chain length (since the difference in teeth between original and new chain rings is only 2 teeth).

How to adjust front derailleur (in your case most likely only the derailleur's height will need to be adjusted):

**when adusting the front derailleur make sure that:**

**1)** The cage is parallel to the chain (scenario C):

[image]

**2)** The derailleur is at the correct height:

[image]
To adjust the height press the derailleur outwards such that the outside part of the cage is hovering over the outer chainring and make sure the distance between the bottom of the cage and the top of the chainring teeth is approx 1-3mm.

Comment: It's not a question of doing it with his current stash of crack, but rather with his current crankset.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I know he wants to re-use his current cranks, that's why I suggested he measure the original chainring's BCD to make sure the new chainrings fit his Praxisworks cranks. Am I missing something?

Comment: You said "crackset".

Comment: @DanielRHicks ah yes my mistake, thanks for pointing it out!